# Properties of integers squareness function

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers

Consider the map
$$
\begin{array}{rccc}
s: &\mathbb{N}_{\geq1} & \longrightarrow & \left(0,1\right]\cap\mathbb{Q}\\
   & n & \longmapsto & \frac{\max\{d|n:\ d\ \leq\ \sqrt{n}\}}{\min\{d|n:\ d\ \geq\ \sqrt{n}\}}
\end{array}
$$
which gives the "squareness" of $n$.

The two following properties should be clear:

1. $n$ is a square number $\Leftrightarrow$ $s(n)=1$
2. $n$ is a prime number $\Leftrightarrow$ $s(n)=\frac{1}{n}$

One nice pattern to display the integer numbers so that the end of each row is a square number is the following:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 \\
2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
\cdots
\end{array}
$$
If we write the values of $s$ applied to this pattern we get:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 \\
\color{red}{1/2} & \color{blue}{1/3} & 1 \\
1/5 & \color{red}{2/3} & 1/7 & \color{blue}{1/2} & 1 \\
2/5 & 1/11 & \color{red}{3/4} & 1/13 & 2/7 & \color{blue}{3/5} & 1 \\
\cdots
\end{array}
$$

The diagonal highlighted in red (formed by taking the $(k-1)$-th value in each row) is given by the relation $s(n)=\frac{k-1}{k}$, i.e. $n=k(k-1)$. These are the [oblong numbers](https://oeis.org/A002378). We can see that after the 1 corresponding to perfect squares, on each row the oblong number attains the maximum value of $s$ (in the end "oblong" can be understood as "quasi-square").

The diagonal highlighted in blue (formed by taking the number before the last in each row) is given by the relation $s(n)=\frac{k-1}{k+1}$, i.e. $n=(k-1)(k+1)=k^2-1$, as we already knew. These are the 3rd-most largest values for $s$ in each row.

> (very open-ended) QUESTION: What other nice properties, derived from the pattern or not, does the squareness function $s$ have?

Comment: It's so common for $p$ to represent only prime numbers that I strongly recommend changing $p$ to some other integer ($d$, say) in your definition of $s(n)$.

Comment: @GregMartin: Thanks, Greg. It's changed now.